# call jquery dialog in master / serverside asp.net page

Tags: jquery

I am working with asp.net master / page and I can not call a jquery dialog from serverside. In head referenzio a masterpage. Js file that initializes the dialog in ... ready. In contentpage I ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript function with the call to the dialog open. The description of the error is: can not call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'open'.
The same dialog works correctly on the client side.